# python - using recursion over nested loop to query ldap

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to work on a small tool where the first step is to query the ldap relationship and store the results in a dictionary, something like this:

```
{'name': 'manager', 'employees': [{'name_s': 'sub_manager', 'employee_s':[{'individual': 'xxx'}, {'individual': 'yyy'}], {'name_s_peers': 'peer_s'}]}

name: manager
 - employees:
  - name_s: sub_manager
   - employee_s:
    - individual: xxx
    - individual: yyy
  - name_s_peers: peer_s
```

I was able to get the outcome using nested for loop, something similar to below

```
def directory_search(username):
    resp = ldapSession.request(url="%s/api/search?query=%s" % (DIRECTORY_BASE, username), method='GET', isJson=False)

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        ldap = json.loads(resp.content)

        username = ldap['elements'][0]['username']

        direct_reports = ldap['elements'][0]['directReports']

        parent_reports = list()
        parent = dict()

        parent['name'] = username
        parent['employees'] = list()

        for i in range(len(direct_reports)):
            direct_reports_user = ldap['elements'][0]['directReports'][i]['username']
            parent_reports.append(direct_reports_user)

        for j in parent_reports:
            resp = ldapSession.request(url="%s/api/search?query=%s" % (DIRECTORY_BASE, j), method='GET', isJson=False)

            if resp.status_code == 200:
                ldap = json.loads(resp.content)

                username = ldap['elements'][0]['username']
                direct_reports = ldap['elements'][0]['directReports']

                second_reports = list()
                second = dict()

                parent['employees'].append(second)

                if direct_reports is not None:
                    for i in range(len(direct_reports)):
                        direct_reports_user = ldap['elements'][0]['directReports'][i]['username']
                        second_reports.append(direct_reports_user)

                        second['name_s'] = username
                        second['employee_s'] = second_reports
                else:
                    second['name_s_peers'] = username

        return parent
```

While this works, I don't think this is the right way to do. Assuming if I have another manager under employee_s, this means I need to write another for loop to get the correct ldap mapping.

I'm trying to use recursion to improve my code but I don't think I'm doing this correctly as the result looks weird so wonder if anyone could help to shed some lights here.

```
{'name': 'manager', 'employees': [{'name_s': 'manager', 'employee_s':['sub_manager', 'peer_s']}
{'name': 'sub_manager', 'employees': [{'name_s': 'sub_manager', 'employee_s':['xxx', 'yyy']}
```

```
def directory_search(username):
    resp = ldapSession.request(url="%s/api/search?query=%s" % (DIRECTORY_BASE, username), method='GET', isJson=False)

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        ldap = json.loads(resp.content)

        username = ldap['elements'][0]['username']

        direct_reports = ldap['elements'][0]['directReports']

        parent_reports = list()
        parent = dict()

        parent['name'] = username
        parent['employees'] = list()

        manager_second = dict()

        if direct_reports is not None:
            for i in range(len(direct_reports)):
                direct_reports_user = ldap['elements'][0]['directReports'][i]['username']
                parent_reports.append(direct_reports_user)

                manager_second['name_s'] = username
                manager_second['employee_s'] = parent_reports

                directory_search(direct_reports_user)

        else:
            manager_second['name_s_peers'] = username

        return parent
```

Answer (score 0):

figure out the problem -

I can just do:

```
parent['employees'] = parent_reports

if direct_reports is not None:
            for i in range(len(direct_reports)):
                direct_reports_user = ldap['elements'][0]['directReports'][i]['username']

                search = directory_search(direct_reports_user)      
                parent_reports.append(search)
```